# d3 svg differentiate onclick

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, onclick

I'm using d3 to add an onClick() event to my svg container.

```
   var svg = d3.select("svg").on("click", ()=>{console.log("svg");});
```

I also have an onclick event for an embedded line Object within the svg;

```
   var line =d3.select("svg").append("line")
               .attr("x1",10)
               .attr("y1",10)
               .attr("x2",100)
               .attr("y2",100)
               .attr("stroke-width",6)
               .attr("stroke","black")
               .on("click" ()=>{console.log("line");})
```

I want both events to be separate in the sense, that whenever I click on the
line I only get the output "line" instead of "line" and "svg".
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using the `preventDefault` function:

```
.on("click" ()=>{
    d3.event.preventDefault();
    console.log("line");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to check on th svg if there any prevented events

```
var svg = d3.select("svg").on("click", ()=>{
                                if(d3.event.defaultPrevented)
                                console.log("svg");});
```

On the line object then I can use preventDefault()

```
var line =d3.select("svg").append("line")
           .attr("x1",10)
           .attr("y1",10)
           .attr("x2",100)
           .attr("y2",100)
           .attr("stroke-width",6)
           .attr("stroke","black")
           .on("click" ()=>{
                     d3.event.preventDefault();
                     console.log("line");})
```